# Modifying .resx file in C#

Tags: c#, resx

I have a `.resx` file that contains name-value pairs (both strings). Now I want to modify the values in certain name-value pairs programmatically using C#. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I'd be curious to hear the use case(s) for this. I have a client that would like to modify resources on the fly, but everything about this seems unnatural and counter to the purposes of resource files.

Comment: I created `ResXResourceManager`-like [classes](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries#dynamic-resource-management) that work the same way as the regular `ResourceManager` but also with write access. Unlike the original `ResXResourceReader`/`*Writer` classes, these are platform independent. Maybe it will be [migrated](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/54657) to .NET 8, but until then you can use it from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KGySoft.CoreLibraries).

Answer (score 28):

There's a whole namespace for resource management: System.Resources.  Check out the ResourceManager class, as well as ResXResourceReader and ResXResourceWriter.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.aspx

---

I managed to lay my hands on a very old debug method that I used to use at one point when I was testing some resource related stuff.  This should do the trick for you.

```
public static void UpdateResourceFile(Hashtable data, String path)
    {
        Hashtable resourceEntries = new Hashtable();

        //Get existing resources
        ResXResourceReader reader = new ResXResourceReader(path);
        if (reader != null)
        {
            IDictionaryEnumerator id = reader.GetEnumerator();
            foreach (DictionaryEntry d in reader)
            {
                if (d.Value == null)
                    resourceEntries.Add(d.Key.ToString(), "");
                else
                    resourceEntries.Add(d.Key.ToString(), d.Value.ToString());
            }
            reader.Close();
        }

        //Modify resources here...
        foreach (String key in data.Keys)
        {
            if (!resourceEntries.ContainsKey(key))
            {

                String value = data[key].ToString();
                if (value == null) value = "";

                resourceEntries.Add(key, value);
            }
        }

        //Write the combined resource file
            ResXResourceWriter resourceWriter = new ResXResourceWriter(path);

            foreach (String key in resourceEntries.Keys)
            {
                resourceWriter.AddResource(key, resourceEntries[key]);
            }
            resourceWriter.Generate();
            resourceWriter.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Is this the only way to UPDATE a kvp in a resx file? It seems like it would just add another kvp to the file.

Comment: The problem is that you will lose the resources comments if that is important for you.

Comment: For those looking to do this on .NET Core, [ResXResourceReader.NetStandard](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ResXResourceReader.NetStandard) offers ResXResourceReader and Writer for .Net Standard

Comment: Unfortunately `System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter ` is not platform independent (resides in `System.Windows.Forms.dll`) and is also very unsafe (loads every possible serialized types from any assembly while parsing the .resx file). For a safer alternative you can use [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KGySoft.CoreLibraries) NuGet package (disclaimer: written by me). [This](https://docs.kgysoft.net/corelibraries/html/N_KGySoft_Resources.htm) page may help to choose the best type for your needs. [GitHub](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries#dynamic-resource-management)

Answer (score 15):

```
public static void AddOrUpdateResource(string key, string value)
{
    var resx = new List<DictionaryEntry>();
    using (var reader = new ResXResourceReader(resourceFilepath))
    {
        resx = reader.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ToList();
        var existingResource = resx.Where(r => r.Key.ToString() == key).FirstOrDefault();
        if (existingResource.Key == null && existingResource.Value == null) // NEW!
        {
            resx.Add(new DictionaryEntry() { Key = key, Value = value });
        }
        else // MODIFIED RESOURCE!
        {
            var modifiedResx = new DictionaryEntry() { Key = existingResource.Key, Value = value };
            resx.Remove(existingResource);  // REMOVING RESOURCE!
            resx.Add(modifiedResx);  // AND THEN ADDING RESOURCE!
        }
    }
    using (var writer = new ResXResourceWriter(ResxPathEn))
    {
        resx.ForEach(r =>
        {
            // Again Adding all resource to generate with final items
            writer.AddResource(r.Key.ToString(), r.Value.ToString());
        });
        writer.Generate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to keep the existing comments in the resource files then use this (Based on SirMoreno's code modified)

```
 public static void UpdateResourceFile(Hashtable data, String path)
    {
        Hashtable resourceEntries = new Hashtable();

        //Get existing resources
        ResXResourceReader reader = new ResXResourceReader(path);
        reader.UseResXDataNodes = true;
        ResXResourceWriter resourceWriter = new ResXResourceWriter(path);
        System.ComponentModel.Design.ITypeResolutionService typeres = null;
        if (reader != null)
        {
            IDictionaryEnumerator id = reader.GetEnumerator();
            foreach (DictionaryEntry d in reader)
            {
                //Read from file:
                string val = "";
                if (d.Value == null)
                    resourceEntries.Add(d.Key.ToString(), "");
                else
                {
                    val = ((ResXDataNode)d.Value).GetValue(typeres).ToString();
                    resourceEntries.Add(d.Key.ToString(), val);

                }

                //Write (with read to keep xml file order)
                ResXDataNode dataNode = (ResXDataNode)d.Value;

                //resourceWriter.AddResource(d.Key.ToString(), val);
                resourceWriter.AddResource(dataNode);

            }
            reader.Close();
        }

        //Add new data (at the end of the file):
        Hashtable newRes = new Hashtable();
        foreach (String key in data.Keys)
        {
            if (!resourceEntries.ContainsKey(key))
            {

                String value = data[key].ToString();
                if (value == null) value = "";

                resourceWriter.AddResource(key, value);
            }
        }

        //Write to file
        resourceWriter.Generate();
        resourceWriter.Close();

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Womp got it right (10x).

But here is a code that keeps the XML file order, add new at the end of the file.
(for source control)

```
    //Need dll System.Windows.Forms
    public static void UpdateResourceFile(Hashtable data, String path)
    {
        Hashtable resourceEntries = new Hashtable();

        //Get existing resources
        ResXResourceReader reader = new ResXResourceReader(path);
        ResXResourceWriter resourceWriter = new ResXResourceWriter(path);

        if (reader != null)
        {
            IDictionaryEnumerator id = reader.GetEnumerator();
            foreach (DictionaryEntry d in reader)
            {
                //Read from file:
                string val = "";
                if (d.Value == null)
                    resourceEntries.Add(d.Key.ToString(), "");
                else
                {
                    resourceEntries.Add(d.Key.ToString(), d.Value.ToString());
                    val = d.Value.ToString();
                }

                //Write (with read to keep xml file order)
                resourceWriter.AddResource(d.Key.ToString(), val);

            }
            reader.Close();
        }

        //Add new data (at the end of the file):
        Hashtable newRes = new Hashtable();
        foreach (String key in data.Keys)
        {
            if (!resourceEntries.ContainsKey(key))
            {

                String value = data[key].ToString();
                if (value == null) value = "";

                resourceWriter.AddResource(key, value);
            }
        }

        //Write to file
        resourceWriter.Generate();
        resourceWriter.Close();

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is improved Womp's answer - without obsolete Hashtable, checking if file exists and using LINQ:

```
    public static void UpdateResourceFile(Dictionary<string, string> data, string path)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> resourceEntries = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            //Get existing resources
            ResXResourceReader reader = new ResXResourceReader(path);
            resourceEntries = reader.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ToDictionary(d => d.Key.ToString(), d => d.Value?.ToString() ?? "");
            reader.Close();
        }

        //Modify resources here...
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in data)
        {
            if (!resourceEntries.ContainsKey(entry.Key))
            {
                if (!resourceEntries.ContainsValue(entry.Value))
                {
                    resourceEntries.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);
                }
            }
        }

        string directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(directoryPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
        }

        //Write the combined resource file
        ResXResourceWriter resourceWriter = new ResXResourceWriter(path);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in resourceEntries)
        {
            resourceWriter.AddResource(entry.Key, resourceEntries[entry.Key]);
        }
        resourceWriter.Generate();
        resourceWriter.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the other answers make use of ResXResourceWriter, but for certain special cases it may be feasible and better to simply work with the Resources.resx file as an XML document.

I have a specific situation where I want to manipulate the Resources.resx entries for a set of icon files. There may be up to several hundred entries, and I can count on them all looking exactly like this:

```
  <data name="Incors_workplace2_16x16" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>..\..\..\..\..\..\Icons\Incors-workplace2-16x16.png;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
  </data>
```

I tried using ResXResourceWriter and ResXResourceReader for this program, but I ended up instead opening the various Resources.resx files as XML documents and manipulating them in that way. The whole program is much too large (and too application-specific) to post here, but I'll post a few stumps of code to show some of the techniques that can be used.

```
      /// <summary>
      /// Method to load a Resources.resx file (if it exists) as an XML Document object.
      /// </summary>
      private static XmlDocument LoadResourcesResx(string projectPath)
      {
         string fileName = projectPath + @"Properties\Resources.resx";
         if (!File.Exists(fileName))
            return null;

         XmlDocument xdResx = new XmlDocument();
         xdResx.Load(fileName);
         return xdResx;
      }

   // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------


      /// <summary>
      /// Method to fix the names of any resources that contain '-' instead of '_'.
      /// </summary>
      private static void FixResourceNames(XmlDocument xdResx, ref bool resxModified)
      {
         // Loop for all of the <data> elements that have name= attributes (node = "name" attr.)
         XmlNodeList xnlDataElements = xdResx.SelectNodes("/root/data/@name");
         if (xnlDataElements != null)
         {
            foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in xnlDataElements)
            {
               // Modify the name= attribute if necessary
               string oldDataName = xmlNode.Value;
               string newDataName = oldDataName.Replace('-', '_');
               if (oldDataName != newDataName)
               {
                  xmlNode.Value = newDataName;
                  resxModified = true;
               }
            }
         }
      }

   // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

            // Prepare to add resource nodes to client-basic's Resources.resx file
            XmlNode rootNodeBasic = xdResx.SelectSingleNode("/root");
   // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

      /// <summary>
      /// Sub-method of above method (not included here) to copy a new icon usage from one of the client-maxi projects 
      /// to the client-basic project.
      /// </summary>
      private static bool CopyIconToClientBasic(string projectPath, XmlDocument xdResxBasic, 
                                                XmlNode rootNodeBasic, XmlNode xmlNodeMaxi)
      {
         // Check if this is an icon-based resource, and get the resource name if so
         string oldDataName = GetAndCheckResourceName(xmlNodeMaxi);
         if (oldDataName == null)
            return false;

         // Determine if there is a 16x16, 20x20, 24x24, 32x32 or 48x48 version of this icon 
         //  available, picking the lowest size to reduce client-basic assembly increase for a 
         //  resource which will probably never be used
         string oldFileName = xmlNodeMaxi.FirstChild.InnerText.Split(';')[0];
         string minSize = FindMinimumIconSize(projectPath, oldFileName);  // Not included here
         if (minSize == null)
            return false;  // Something wrong, can't find icon file

         // Test if client-basic's resources includes a version of this icon for smallest size
         string newDataName = oldDataName.Remove(oldDataName.Length - 5) + minSize;
         if (xdResxBasic.SelectSingleNode("/root/data[@name='" + newDataName + "']") != null)
            return false;  // Already in client-basic

         // Add the smallest available size version of this icon to the client-basic project
         string oldSize = oldDataName.Substring(oldDataName.Length - 5);  // "16x16", "20x20"
         XmlNode newNodeBasic = xdResxBasic.ImportNode(xmlNodeMaxi, true);
         if (newNodeBasic.Attributes != null)
            newNodeBasic.Attributes["name"].Value = newDataName;  // Maybe force smaller size
         newNodeBasic.FirstChild.InnerText =
                                  newNodeBasic.FirstChild.InnerText.Replace(oldSize, minSize);
         rootNodeBasic.AppendChild(newNodeBasic);
         return true;
      }

   // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

      /// <summary>
      /// Method to filter out non-icon resources and return the resource name for the icon-based 
      /// resource in the Resources.resx object.
      /// </summary>
      /// <returns>name of resource, i.e., name= value, or null if not icon resource</returns>
      private static string GetAndCheckResourceName(XmlNode xmlNode)
      {
         // Ignore resources that aren't PNG-based icon files with a standard size. This 
         //  includes ignoring ICO-based resources.
         if (!xmlNode.FirstChild.InnerText.Contains(";System.Drawing.Bitmap,"))
            return null;
         if (xmlNode.Attributes == null)
            return null;

         string dataName = xmlNode.Attributes["name"].Value;

         if (dataName.EndsWith("_16x16", StringComparison.Ordinal) ||
             dataName.EndsWith("_20x20", StringComparison.Ordinal) ||
             dataName.EndsWith("_24x24", StringComparison.Ordinal) ||
             dataName.EndsWith("_32x32", StringComparison.Ordinal) ||
             dataName.EndsWith("_48x48", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            return dataName;

         return null;
      }

   // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

         // It's too messy to create a new node from scratch when not using the ResXResourceWriter 
         //  facility, so we cheat and clone an existing icon entry, the one for Cancel buttons

         // Get the Cancel icon name and filename
         BuiltInIcon cancelIcon = BuiltInIconNames.FindIconByName(BuiltInIconNames.CCancel);
         string cancelIconResourceName = cancelIcon.ResourceName + "_16x16";

         // Find it in the Resources.resx file - it should be there
         XmlNode cancelIconNode = 
                 xdResxBasic.SelectSingleNode("/root/data[@name='" + cancelIconResourceName + "']");
         if (cancelIconNode == null)
         {
            PreprocessorMain.DisplayError(0x27b699fu, "Icon " + cancelIconResourceName + 
                                                      " not found in Resources.resx file.");
            return false;
         }

         // Make a clone of this node in the Resources.resx file
         XmlNode newNode = cancelIconNode.Clone();
         if (newNode.Attributes == null) // Not possible?
         {
            PreprocessorMain.DisplayError(0x27b8038u, "Node for icon " + cancelIconResourceName + 
                                                      " not as expected in Resources.resx file.");
            return false;
         }

         // Modify the cloned XML node to represent the desired icon file/resource and add it to the 
         //  Resources.resx file
         newNode.Attributes["name"].Value = iconResourceName;
         newNode.InnerText = 
                  newNode.InnerText.Replace(cancelIcon.FileNameNoSize + "-16x16.png", iconFileName);
         rootNodeBasic.AppendChild(newNode);
         resxModified = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

In visual studio, go to the resource manager window than you will see a menu top of it "Access Modifier" change it to public and save. It will be updated

Answer (score 0):

This is my version based on Ers' and based on SirMoreno's code. Just a little shorter. This is still not handeling metaData which is possible but not necessasry for me.

```
    public static bool AddToResourceFile(string key, string value, string comment, string path)
    {
        using (ResXResourceWriter resourceWriter = new ResXResourceWriter(path))
        {
            //Get existing resources
            using (ResXResourceReader reader = new ResXResourceReader(path) { UseResXDataNodes = true })
            {
                foreach (DictionaryEntry resEntry in reader)
                {
                    ResXDataNode node = resEntry.Value as ResXDataNode;
                    if (node == null) continue;

                    if (string.CompareOrdinal(key, node.Name) == 0)
                    {
                        // Keep resources untouched. Alternativly modify this resource.
                        return false;
                    }

                    resourceWriter.AddResource(node);
                }
            }

            //Add new data (at the end of the file):
            resourceWriter.AddResource(new ResXDataNode(key, value) { Comment = comment });

            //Write to file
            resourceWriter.Generate();
        }
        return true;
    }
```