# Appending resources to a .resx file

Tags: .net, resources

How I can open an existing .resx file, write some resources and close without losing the resources that were in the original file?

Comment: Isn't that the default behavior already? I don't usually lose any existing resources when editing .resx files. Are you not using Visual Studio as your editor?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modifying .resx file in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676312/modifying-resx-file-in-c)

Comment: I'm using ResXResourceWriter for resource writing

Comment: It is possible (although maybe not the best technique) to work on a Resources.resx file as an XML document. http://stackoverflow.com/a/43431478/253938

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ResXResourceWriter just writes the new nodes.. To keep the old ones you can do like this :
The code below will add one new node to the resx file and by iterating the old nodes writing them again. I bet there is a more simple way in doing this, but can't figure it out.

```
var reader = new ResXResourceReader("filename");
var node = reader.GetEnumerator();
var writer = new ResXResourceWriter("filename");
while (node.MoveNext())
{
    writer.AddResource(node.Key.ToString(), node.Value.ToString());
}
var newNode = new ResXDataNode("name", "value");
writer.AddResource(newNode);
writer.Generate();
writer.Close();
```

Remember to add the using [System.Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.aspx)