# Modifying existing resource file programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, resources

I am using the following code to generate resource file programmatically.

```
ResXResourceWriter resxWtr = new ResXResourceWriter(@"C:\CarResources.resx");
resxWtr.AddResource("Title", "Classic American Cars");
resxWtr.Generate();
resxWtr.Close();
```

Now, I want to modify the resource file created from the above code. If I use the same code, the existing resource file gets replaced. How to modify it without losing the existing contents?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem this resolve it:

This will append to your existing .resx file

```
 var reader = new ResXResourceReader(@"C:\CarResources.resx");//same fileName
 var node = reader.GetEnumerator();
 var writer = new ResXResourceWriter(@"C:\CarResources.resx");//same fileName(not new)
 while (node.MoveNext())
         {
     writer.AddResource(node.Key.ToString(), node.Value.ToString());
       }
  var newNode = new ResXDataNode("Title", "Classic American Cars");
  writer.AddResource(newNode);
  writer.Generate();
  writer.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that would help you modify the resource file.

```
public static void UpdateResourceFile(Hashtable data, String path)
{
    Hashtable resourceEntries = new Hashtable();

    //Get existing resources
    ResXResourceReader reader = new ResXResourceReader(path);
    if (reader != null)
    {
        IDictionaryEnumerator id = reader.GetEnumerator();
        foreach (DictionaryEntry d in reader)
        {
            if (d.Value == null)
                resourceEntries.Add(d.Key.ToString(), "");
            else
                resourceEntries.Add(d.Key.ToString(), d.Value.ToString());
        }
        reader.Close();
    }

    //Modify resources here...
    foreach (String key in data.Keys)
    {
        if (!resourceEntries.ContainsKey(key))
        {

            String value = data[key].ToString();
            if (value == null) value = "";

            resourceEntries.Add(key, value);
        }
    }

    //Write the combined resource file
        ResXResourceWriter resourceWriter = new ResXResourceWriter(path);

        foreach (String key in resourceEntries.Keys)
        {
            resourceWriter.AddResource(key, resourceEntries[key]);
        }
        resourceWriter.Generate();
        resourceWriter.Close();

}
```

Reference link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676312/modifying-resx-file-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I don't want to re-write existing resource file, i just want to append new resources to it. Is there any other way?