# Resources added and deleted at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a resource file called "sample.resx". It contains 5 strings (and I want it to contain strings only, I don't want pictures and other stuff). I want to modify this file by adding and deleting records.
What I want to achieve is that I want to have these resources modified after closing the *.exe and have all my necessary strings in one place.
Is it even possible to do it? Do I have to make some extra files?
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, you have asked a duplicate question, so your question will soon be closed by the community. However, you can find a solution in the [Modifying .resx file in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676312/modifying-resx-file-in-c-sharp) post instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for help :)
But, actually, the type ResXResourceReader can't be found - why?

Comment: You're welcome. If you're going to make further use of Stack Overflow, you might find that you get more out of this sire if you read through some of the pages in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). You'll find a lot of useful information there.

Comment: Are you missing a reference to `System.Resources`?

Comment: No, I have the reference included.

Comment: Follow the advice in the [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page of the Help Center and if you still haven't found a solution, then please ask a new question.