# C# windows form save recently browsed file history

Tags: c#

I wrote an app in C# which allows user to select a directory and does some simple things on the files in the directory. Now I want to add a ListBox to it that saves the most recent 5 selected directories. I don't want to hook up my app to a db because it's a very simple app. I can save the values to a txt file but I don't think that's the best practice. Is there any built-in features in Visual Studio Windows Form Application which allows me to do that? (I tried *.resx file and it doesn't seems to work for such purpose.)

Comment: Project + Properties, Settings tab.  A StringCollection is the natural choice.

Comment: look here for some good examples http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.aspx || http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676312/modifying-resx-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: File is the good choice.

Comment: But Settings are easy for manipulation. We don't need to open ‚ save and close file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of Settings can do this feature. It is so sample just go to the project properties and add a new propertie with type StringCollection .
You can manipulate this propertie like a sample collection by add ‚remove  paths.
Take a look in this  tutorial : http://blog.csharphelper.com/2011/08/18/use-a-setting-that-contains-a-string-collection-in-c.aspx