# custom client localization form Win Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, localization

I have big WinForms project,and now i need to create module,where client can create/update/delete its own localization to a project (dataGrid Name-Value,like resx files).Also we need a default localization.But in WinForms every form has own resx file=( What the best way to realize this feature?Xml file or it could be done by resx files.
In previous version of the project (unfortunately no source code) it was jsut text Key-Value file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are diffrent way to approch that topic. On top of my head i have 2 solutions for that problem.

**First solution**

Since *.resx files are compiled into executable you cannot really modify them, but since you are using them already easiest approach would be to change reference from original build in *.resx file to one you have made and put in your folder hierarchy. That way you could use your build in files as default and search for other languages if they exists replace them.

This might help you [Modifying .resx file in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676312/modifying-resx-file-in-c-sharp)
Downside of this approach is that resx files are c# classes and could be realy hard to edit outside of Visual Studio editor.

**Second solution**

If you have time to move all of your default texts to *.xml files you could do that and use similar approach like in *.resx file. Since i found it easier to create and edit xml files this could save your day. Downside of that approach is time required to connect every string to your windows forms app.