# Is it possible to update .resx file at runtime in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, localization, resx

I have a resx file in my Xamarin.forms project, and I have webapi that returns translations in key value pair format. Is there any possible way that I can update my resx files using those key value pairs at run-time.(Not interested Sqlite way of Localization)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676312/modifying-resx-file-in-c-sharp)?

Comment: @Tom I think it's for WPF, I want to do this in Xamarin.Forms. There is no ResXResourceReader  class available with Xam forms

Comment: Unfortunately, now is not possible to do that.Maybe you can use customed .json file to update at runtime.

Comment: @FavasKv, how did you finally stored and used translations retrieved from webapi?

Comment: @MukeshModhvadiya I created a singleton class with list of key-value pair translations.

Comment: @FavasKv, Thanks for the information! And you also stored the translations in file/db?

Comment: @MukeshModhvadiya Yes, it stored in db and updated on each run using api call.